# How to plot a dose-response model in R?

Tags: r, model, soil

I am relatively new to the R game, and thus trying to convert my data analysis to R.

In excel I have fit a kinetic model to explain variation in yield as a function of Manganese availability.

I would like to plot the model in R, in conjunction with my experimental data.

I have tried already to plot the model Y values with sample X values, and since they are not ordered, the line does not plot correctly.

Can anyone help?

Perhaps there is a simple way to fit a model with defined parameters to experimental data?

Comment: Can you please include a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: Please provide the example. Share more information and tag accordingly so people can reach you

Comment: Do the following: [1] Import your data into R. [2] Type `dput(mydata)` and add the output of that to your question. [3] Specify the model formula for your kinetic model (are we supposed to guess??). There is also an general expectation that you would have at least tried you do this yourself (so, include what you've tried already). But as you're new to this we can do without that for the moment.

Comment: Try the drc R packaqe.

Comment: Ultimately it would be nice to have R solve the model.  I fit the curve in excel and then exported data based on known parameters.

Comment: Model equation is :
Q(t) = Qmax*(1-a*exp(-kt))+c   where a, k, c are hittable parameters

I have since figured out a roundabout way of plotting the model.  Any input and advice would still be graciously accepted.

    
   `data <- read.csv ("Mn_model.csv", header = TRUE)
    data$sample <- as.factor(data$sample) 
    str(data)

    ##creating the function of the defined model
    t <- data$cdgt
    ymax <- 7.0811
    a <- .3590
    k <- 0.0027
    c <- -0.3510
    model <- function(t) {ymax*(1-a*exp(-k*t))+c}`

@jlhoward

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  

Had trouble installing this pkg.  installed dependencies and it failed to load the library.

Comment: @BH_, It installs and runs fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the classic sigmoid dose-response curve, try the ecotoxicology R package. It's an implementation of the EPA's Ecological exposure Research Division (EERD) tools (discontinued in 1999) for Probit and Trimmed Spearman-Karber Analysis.

Another option is morse: MOdelling Tools for Reproduction and Survival Data in Ecotoxicology.

> "Tools for ecotoxicologists and regulators dedicated to the
>   mathematical and statistical modelling of bioassay data. They use
>   advanced and innovative methods for a valuable quantitative
>   environmental risk assessment."

This includes some metals examples and survival data. drc may also be an option (as mentioned above). There's a free publication that illustrates uses and extensions of drc, ["Dose-Response Analysis Using R"](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0146021&type=printable)